# Why can we assume that the range of the generator of a $C_0$ semigroup is already the full space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators, stochastic-pde, closed-graph

I am reading this script: http://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs.pdf about stochastic partial differential equations. I have a problem with the footnote on page 46.

$L$ is the generator of some $C_0$ semigroup on a Banach space $B$ (one can assume separability here but I think that doesn't play a role).

From that we know that $L$ is a closed operator and the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ is dense in $B$.

In the footnote he wants to show that some subspace of $B^*$ already seperates points in $B$ and what he needs to show is that the range of the adjoint operator $L^*: B^* \to B^*$ is already all of $B^*$.

The first thing he does is assume that the range of $L$ is already all of $B$ and says we can do that without loss of generality. And here I am lost already. I don't even recall that the range should be dense in $B$ and even if, I don't see how you can make such a strong assumption w.l.o.g..

(Actually I don't understand his argumentation afterwards too and how exactly he applies the closed graph theorem, but if I assume that the range $\mathcal{R}(L)$ is already $B$ from my view one could just apply the closed range theorem and its corollary [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_range_theorem))

Comment: If $T(t)$ is a bounded $C_0$ semigroup with generator $A$, then the spectrum of $A$ is in the left half-plane. So $\lambda I+A$ has full range for any $\lambda > 0$. That may be enough for the proof.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts thanks very much for the answer. I am allthough not sure that I can assume a bounded C^0 semigroup here. This means I only have that the spectrum of $A$ is in $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} | \text{re}(\lambda) \le a\}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$, possibly greater than 0

Comment: If he is able to assume the range of $L$ is all of $B$, then he is probably assuming something like that.